# Android Studio - how to get Eclipse like Cmd+Mouse click shortcut?

Tags: macos, android-studio, click, mouse, mouseover

I'm using Android Studio (ver 1.0.1, on OSX Mavericks) for the first time and was wondering how I could get the eclipse like mouse shortcuts like Cmd + Mouse click to jump to definition etc

I couldn't find this in my online searching or in the Preferences. Does anyone know how ? Or is this not available yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I figured out the answer. 
Open Preferences -> Keymap -> Search for "Declaration" -> double click on the search result under the 'Navigate' category -> select "add mouse shortcut" -> and press the shortcut buttons (eg. CMD+left click) and save it

Answer (score 1):

You can also `cmd+B` for that, after selecting the occurence you want to navigate to.